# SQL CASE WHEN with multiple AND and OR

Tags: sql

Can you please tell me if SQL code below makes sense. I am using multiple `ANDs` and `OR` in `CASE WHEN`. 
Thanks for your help!

```
SELECT id, period,
 CASE WHEN state = 'group8' AND mathscore = 0 AND manager = '' OR manager ISNULL 
 THEN 'Tom' ELSE manager END AS mgr, 

 CASE WHEN state = 'group8' AND mathscore = 0 AND associate = '' OR associate 
 ISNULL THEN 'Dick' ELSE associate END AS asso,

 CASE WHEN state = 'group8' AND mathscore = 0 AND analyst = '' OR analyst ISNULL 
 THEN 'Harry' ELSE analyst END AS a

 FROM class.sections
```

Comment: Does it give you the results you expect?

Comment: I have no idea if this logic works for you needs since you don't state what your trying to do. It syntactically correct so... good there. But I'm gonna wager a guess that you mean `WHEN state = 'group8' AND mathscore = 0 AND (manager = '' OR manager IS NULL)` Those parentheses are important.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We might be able to assist you if you provide more context and details with what you're trying to do, and the expected output. Look into [effectively asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Instead of `AND manager = '' OR manager ISNULL`, you could also do `AND ISNULL(manager,'') = ''` or `AND COALESCE(manager,'') = ''`. This is assuming that you meant to have those two things grouped together.

Comment: And just a note, when SQL sees `WHEN state = 'group8' AND mathscore = 0 AND manager = '' OR manager ISNULL`, it interprets `WHEN (state = 'group8' AND mathscore = 0 AND manager = '') OR (manager ISNULL)`. So you could have `state = 'group42'` with `manager = NULL'`, and you'd end up with `manager` as `Tom` instead of `NULL`. Explicit grouping can reduce the chance of unintended results.

Answer (score 4):

When using ANDs and ORs you should enclose in parentheses to avoid unwanted results. i.e:

```
CASE WHEN (state = 'group8' AND mathscore = 0)
AND (manager = '' OR manager ISNULL)
THEN 'Tom' ELSE manager END AS mgr
```

is not the same as:

```
CASE WHEN (state = 'group8' AND mathscore = 0 AND manager = '')
OR manager ISNULL 
THEN 'Tom' ELSE manager END AS mgr
```

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data to work with, I'd wager you're looking for something like this, with your blanks and NULLs grouped together with parentheses.

Also, I changed your `ISNULL`s (a function, in some dialects) to `IS NULL` (a state, in SQL Server, anyway).

```
SELECT
  id
 ,period
 ,CASE
    WHEN state = 'group8'
         AND mathscore = 0
         AND (manager = ''
             OR manager IS NULL) THEN 'Tom'
    ELSE manager
  END AS mgr
 ,CASE
    WHEN state = 'group8'
         AND mathscore = 0
         AND (associate = ''
             OR associate IS NULL) THEN 'Dick'
    ELSE associate
  END AS asso
 ,CASE
    WHEN state = 'group8'
         AND mathscore = 0
         AND (analyst = ''
             OR analyst IS NULL) THEN 'Harry'
    ELSE analyst
  END AS a
FROM
  class.sections;
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, NiMusco and JNevil. It was that bracket that I was missing and ofcourse it should be IS NULL and not ISNULL. It's finally working the way I wanted. Really appreciate your help! :)